# Why does using a variable in a function change the value returned in R when using superassignment (<<-) operator?

Tags: r, function, lexical-scope

Why do bar and baz behave differently? When bar is called both the value of a printed and the value of a in the global scope are the same, but when baz is called the printed value and the value in the global scope are different. Seemingly, the only difference is that a is used (but not defined) in a parent environment.

```
a = 1:3
b = 4
foo <- function(a) {
  a[1] <<- b
  print(a)
}

bar <- function(a) {
  foo(a)
}

baz <- function(a) {
  a
  foo(a)
}

bar(a) # 4 2 3
a # 4 2 3 

a <- 1:3
baz(a) # 1 2 3
a # 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Complex assignment operator `<<-` changes the value of a variable in the parent environment. When `bar` is called:

- It passes `a` to `foo`
- `foo` then changes the value of first element of `a` to `4` in global environment
- After that `foo` prints `a`

```
> bar(a) # 4 2 3
[1] 4 2 3
```

The only thing to note here is, since `foo` was created in global environment, it searches for the value of `b` through lexical scoping in the environment where it was created which is again global environment. Such is the case when `foo` prints `a` in the end, it again searches for its value in the environment where it was created which is global environment.
So the `a` will change to `c(4, 2, 3)`.

However, when you call `baz`,

- It first prints `a` which is the original `c(1, 2, 3)`
- Then it passes it to `foo` where the same thing that I explained above happens

So that's why the first print is the original `a` and the second is the modified one.

A resume of our discussion in comments:

- The first line of code in baz (first one) is a which is equivalent to print(a). In your second baz the output is the same cause the output for the first line of code is not returned. No matter if you use mean or sum. If you want the output you should use print() and force it to return. In that case the output of foo(a) won't return. But if you want both you can just use a list for example
- The other reason that the output is still 1:3 has got nothing to do with mean , it is because of foo. Cause it changes the first value of object a in the global environment. But then it prints the value of argument a. There is difference here between free variable a that foo finds through lexical scoping in global env and argument a which you assign yourself to `baz` to be then passed to foo
- Just note that using a in the first `baz` is like using print(a) so whatever is printed is the result of what `baz` does not foo contrary to what I explain above
- You can use rm(a) to remove a from global environment and use `baz <- function(a) {   foo(a) } and baz(c(1,2,3)` to better differentiate between the object `a` and argument `a`

Comment: Where is it printing a in baz? If I change it to

`
baz <- function(a) {
  mean(a)
  foo(a)
}`

It has the same result. Just by virtue of the fact that a is used (but not defined) in baz it changes the result.

Comment: The first line of code in `baz` (first one) is `a` which is equivalent to `print(a)`. In your second `baz` the output is the same cause the output for the first line of code is not returned. No matter if you use `mean` or `sum`. If you want the output you should use `print()` and force it to return. In that case the output of `foo(a)` won't return. But if you want both you can just use a `list` for example.

Comment: The other reason that the output is still `1:3` has got nothing to do with `mean` , it is because of `foo`. Cause it changes the first value of object `a` in the global environment. But then it prints the value of argument `a`. There is difference here between free variable `a` that foo finds through lexical scoping in global env and argument `a` which you assign yourself to `buz` to be then passed to `foo`.

Comment: Just note that using `a` in the first `buz` is like using `print(a)` so whatever is printed is the result of what `baz` does not `foo` contrary to what I explain above.

Comment: You can use `rm(a)` to remove `a` from global environment and use `baz <- function(a) {
  foo(a)
}` and `baz(c(1,2,3)` to better differentiate between the object `a` and argument `a`.

Comment: "The first line of code in baz (first one) is a which is equivalent to print(a)" --


This is not the case inside a function scope, only in the global scope (and even then there is still a slight difference). I actually think the reason has something to do with lazy evaluation. In bar, a is never evaluated so it only exists in the global scope, but in baz a is evaluated so it is copied into foo and also exists in the global scope.